# Why anhydrous acetic acid is differentiating solvent?

Tags: acid-base, solvents

Anhydrous acetic acid is differentiating solvent in which strong acids show different strength but water isn't. Why anhydrous acetic acid shows the strength of acids clearly, but water solvent cannot do so?

Comment: see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leveling_effect

Comment: Every basic solvent will "weaken" dissolved acid which is stronger than solvents conjugated acid, but protonated acetic acid is **very** strong.

Comment: @Mithoron thanks your point is great for answer.